# Stoke's Theorem Example

Tags: stokes-theorem

"Use the surface integral in Stoke's Theorem to calculate the circulation of the field **F**=$⟨x^2,2x,z^2 ⟩$ around the curve $C,$ where $C$ is the ellipse $4x^2+y^2=4$ in the $xy$ plane, counterclockwise from above."

**My Work So Far:**

The circulation is $\int_C$**F**$\cdot dr$, meaning that it can be found with $\int\int_S curl$ **F** $\cdot ds$

$curl$ **F** $= ⟨ 0,0,2⟩$

$\int\int_S ⟨ 0,0,2⟩$  $\cdot ds = \int_C$**F**$\cdot dr$

From here, though, I'm confused about what to do for $ds$ and the boundaries. The boundaries in particular are strange because of the elliptical shape; polar coordinates aren't appropriate because there's no circular component, but trying to remain in $x$ and $y$ results in a very ugly $y_{-\sqrt{4-4x^2} \to \sqrt{4-4x^2}}$, which doesn't seem right either.

I feel like this is intended to be a fairly simple example of Stoke's theorem but I'm having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around it. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should not do the integral (although you can). The answer will be twice the area of the filled-in ellipse. Do you know what the area of an ellipse with semi-axes $a$ and $b$ is? (If you know a bit of linear algebra or the change of variables in a double integral, you can easily deduce this from the area of a unit circle.)

Comment: I understand that I can just look up the area of an ellipse, but that won't always be the case. I'm trying to figure out how I would do the integral properly so that I can apply the logic to future examples.

Comment: Do you know how to do change of variables with a Jacobian determinant in a double (or triple) integral? If so, you can use a "stretched" version of polar coordinates. If not, proceed as you're going. That isn't going to be that tough an integral to do. (Note that $\sqrt4=2$ and $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ is one you should know how to do.) That said, I always wanted my students to use symmetry and use easier ways to solve these integrals when we were doing Stokes's and Divergence Theorems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

You can evaluate the integral as:
$$\int\int_S ⟨ 0,0,2⟩\cdot ds=
2\int_{-1}^{1} dx\int_{-2\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{2\sqrt{1-x^2}} dy=8\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}dx
$$

can you see that this is double the area of the ellipse of half-axis $1$ and $2$?